# Aggregate of aggregate with EF Core Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 project with EF Core 2.2 Code-First DB. I have the following entities:

- Building, which is basically an address with some other important data.
- Floor, which contains the number of the floor. A building can have multiple floors. A floor has to have exactly one building where it's located.
- Room, which has a number. A floor can have multiple rooms. A room has to have exactly one floor.
- WorkGroup, which contains how many employees are int the group, whether the group is still active, and when did the group started to operate (which can be in the future).
- RoomOccupancy, which is a join table between a WorkGroup and a room and shows in which room a WorkGroup is/was/will be.

I need a list of the buildings with the buildings name, how many floors it has, how many rooms the building has (not a floor), and how many people currently works int the building.

Currently I'm able to get all the data, but the translated SQL is not optimal and takes many trips to the DB. I was able to write one SQL select statement (with inner select) by hand for the problem, so I know this should be possible with one query.

```cs
dbContext.Buildings.Select(x=> new BuildingDatableElementDTO(){
            BuildingId = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            FloorCount = b.Floors.Count(),
            //this is the part where problems start,
            //this translates to multiple SQL statements
            RoomCount = b.Floors.Sum(f=>f.Rooms.Count()),
            // I replaced the next line with
            // CurrentWorkerCount = 10, but a solution would be nice
            CurrentWorkerCount = b.Floors.Sum(f=>f.Rooms
              .Sum(r=>r.RoomOccupancies
                 .Where(o=>!o.WorkGroup.IsFinished && o.WorkGroup.StartDate < Datetime.Now).
                 .Sum(w => w.NumberOfEmployees)
                 ))),
    }).ToList();
```

For testing purposes I have replaced the CurrentWorkerCount lambda with CurrentWorkerCount = 10, because I can understand if it's hard to translate to SQL, but it still fails to create one SQL statement with the RoomCount.

Logging with info level shows this: "The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally" for every building that has at least one floor.
Then I have one bigger DbCommand (too long to copy), then one DbCommand for every building, which counts the number of rooms.

I read that there are problems with the aggregates with EF Core 2.1, but I think it shouldn't be a hard task for the ORM to translate this Projection into one query.

Am I doing something wrong there or these are the capabilities of the LINQ and the EF Core? I think I could easily do that with the non-Core EF previously. I read about some workarounds for GroupBy and aggregates, but it didn't help in my case.

**UPDATE**

Here is the generated log (only the interesting parts). I'm using a custom solution for filtering, sorting and paging which works great with simple problems. No filtering in this example, sorting by the buildings name and basic fetch (skip 0 take 15). There is only a minimal amount of test data in the database (15 buildings one has 1 floor, another one has 2, of which one has 1 room, which has 1 workgroup with 100 employees). I also have soft delete with a global filter configured for the IsDeleted flag. I don't think these things affect the results, but here they are, maybe they do.

- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- The LINQ expression '"Sum()"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
- Executed DbCommand ("2"ms) [Parameters=["@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), [x].[Id]) AS [BuildingId], [x].[Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Floors] AS [x0]
    WHERE ([x0].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x].[Id] = [x0].[BuildingId])
) AS [FloorCount], [x].[Id]
FROM [Buildings] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[IsDeleted] = 0
ORDER BY [x].[Name]
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@__Now_2='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @_outer_Id3='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM([x14].[NumberOfEmployees])
    FROM [RoomOccupancys] AS [x14]
    LEFT JOIN [WorkGroups] AS [k.WorkGroup2] ON [x14].[WorkGroupId] = [k.WorkGroup2].[Id]
    WHERE (([x14].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (([k.WorkGroup2].[IsFinished] = 0) AND ([k.WorkGroup2].[StartDate] < @__Now_2))) AND ([x13].[Id] = [x14].[RoomId])
)
FROM [Rooms] AS [x13]
WHERE ([x13].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id3 = [x13].[FloorId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@__Now_2='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @_outer_Id3='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM([x14].[RemainingAmount])
    FROM [RoomOccupancys] AS [x14]
    LEFT JOIN [WorkGroups] AS [k.WorkGroup2] ON [x14].[WorkGroupId] = [k.WorkGroup2].[Id]
    WHERE (([x14].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (([k.WorkGroup2].[IsFinished] = 0) AND ([k.WorkGroup2].[StartDate] < @__Now_2))) AND ([x13].[Id] = [x14].[RoomId])
)
FROM [Rooms] AS [x13]
WHERE ([x13].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id3 = [x13].[FloorId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])
```

- Executed DbCommand ("0"ms) [Parameters=["@_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Guid)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"

```sql
SELECT [x10].[Id]
FROM [Floors] AS [x10]
WHERE ([x10].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [x10].[BuildingId])
```

Comment: It isn't always possible to generate efficient SQL via LINQ translation. Can you show the SQL query? Your code appears to mix `x` and `b`? You say you are using LINQ to SQL but it looks like you are using Linq to EF Core 2.1?

Comment: Note that multiple SQL queries isn't always less efficient than one, depending on the data distribution.

Comment: Is one SQL statement being generated per `Floors` or per `Building` for the `Sum`?

Comment: @NetMage Updated with the generated log. I don't think this isn't an efficient solution, since the db barely had any data. Oh and this is the log with the "real" CurentWorkerCount , not the =10.

Comment: @NetMage just cheked with CurrentWorkerCount=10, it calls the one with the nested select 15 times (which is the number of buildings in the db). My problem is that I can have a far greater number of records in production. Even if every call takes just 1 ms, 500 of them means half a second of wait for the data, which is not great, but not terrible :)

Comment: Just forget it. The possibilities of shaping the generated SQL are very limited, esp. with EF-core. You will never keep it from generating multiple queries and I'm pretty sure that most of the query is even evaluated client-side, so it pulls far more data into memory than strictly necessary. BTW, the repeated `Sum`s can be replaced by `SelectMany` and one `Sum`, which will probably generate slightly less inefficient SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks, I had a felling that this was the case. I tried SelectMany, it's probably slightly better (I didn't add enough test data yet), but I hoped this had a solution. As far as I remember, EF handled things like that adequately but I haven't used it in 1.5 half year. Guess I'll write stored procedures or probably set up cqrs with elastisearch or something.

Comment: You're probably used to EF6. EF6 at least generates *decent* SQL, which is the best an ORM can do. EF core has a long way to go yet.

Comment: While in general I agree with @GertArnold (and have said EF Core is not ready for production), I think EF Core 2.1 is usable, and EF Core 3.x should be much better.

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with `FloorCount` as well, it appears to be running a separate query for each building for that. I did see where `Count()` may be a problem for EF Core in some cases. I guess you have the not deleted criteria on the `Floors` virtual collection? Does adding `Include(b => b.Floors).ThenInclude(f => f.Rooms)` before the `Select` help any?

Comment: @NetMage I'll check but I don't think so. As far as I know with instantiating in the select there is no need for includes and if I remember right they even get optimalized out by the EF. Amd yeah, I have soft delete set up on the Floor entities.

Comment: @NetMage yeah, this is in the logs: "The Include operation for navigation '"[s].Floors.Rooms"' is unnecessary and was ignored because the navigation is not reachable in the final query results. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850303 for more information.

Comment: @NetMage when I used the CurrentWorker = 10 instead of the long linq, the Floor soft delete checks disappeared. I only had as many 
`SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Rooms] AS [x4]
    WHERE ([x4].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([x3].[Id] = [x4].[FloorId])
)
FROM [Floors] AS [x3]
WHERE ([x3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (@_outer_Id = [x3].[BuildingId])` 
 as many Buildings I fetched for the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that there are problems with the aggregates with EF Core 2.1, but I think it shouldn't be a hard task for the ORM to translate this Projection into one query.

You are right that EF Core had (and still have - the latest at this time v2.2) problems translating `GroupBy` and aggregates (and not only). But not for *"shouldn't be a hard task"* - try converting arbitrary expression tree to pseudo SQL yourself and you'll quickly find that it is quite complicated task.

Anyway, EF Core query translation improves over the time, but as mentioned, is far from perfect. The showstopper in this case are nested aggregates - sum of sum/count etc. The solution is to flatten the target set and apply single aggregate. For instance, rewriting your LINQ query as follows:

```
dbContext.Buildings.Select(b => new //BuildingDatableElementDTO()
{
    BuildingId = b.Id,
    Name = b.Name,
    FloorCount = b.Floors.Count(),
    // (1)
    RoomCount = b.Floors.SelectMany(f => f.Rooms).Count(),
    // (2)
    CurrentWorkerCount = b.Floors
        .SelectMany(f => f.Rooms)
        .SelectMany(r => r.RoomOccupancies)
        .Select(o => o.WorkGroup)
        .Where(w => !w.IsFinished && w.StartDate < DateTime.Now)
        .Sum(w => w.NumberOfEmployees),
})
.ToList();
```

is translated to a single SQL (as expected):

```sql
  SELECT [e].[Id] AS [BuildingId], [e].[Name], (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [Floors] AS [e0]
      WHERE ([e0].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([e].[Id] = [e0].[BuildingId])
  ) AS [FloorCount], (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [Floors] AS [e1]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [e2].[Id], [e2].[FloorId], [e2].[IsDeleted], [e2].[Name]
          FROM [Rooms] AS [e2]
          WHERE [e2].[IsDeleted] = 0
      ) AS [t] ON [e1].[Id] = [t].[FloorId]
      WHERE ([e1].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([e].[Id] = [e1].[BuildingId])
  ) AS [RoomCount], (
      SELECT SUM([f.Rooms.RoomOccupancies.WorkGroup].[NumberOfEmployees])
      FROM [Floors] AS [e3]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [e4].*
          FROM [Rooms] AS [e4]
          WHERE [e4].[IsDeleted] = 0
      ) AS [t0] ON [e3].[Id] = [t0].[FloorId]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [e5].*
          FROM [RoomOccupancies] AS [e5]
          WHERE [e5].[IsDeleted] = 0
      ) AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[RoomId]
      INNER JOIN [WorkGroups] AS [f.Rooms.RoomOccupancies.WorkGroup] ON [t1].[WorkgroupId] = [f.Rooms.RoomOccupancies.WorkGroup].[Id]
      WHERE (([e3].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND (([f.Rooms.RoomOccupancies.WorkGroup].[IsFinished] = 0) AND ([f.Rooms.RoomOccupancies.WorkGroup].[StartDate] < GETDATE()))) AND ([e].[Id] = [e3].[BuildingId])
  ) AS [CurrentWorkerCount]
  FROM [Building] AS [e]
  WHERE [e].[IsDeleted] = 0
```

Comment: Wow, I never expected EF core to be able to handle this and gave up before even trying. Seeing the SQL query, it even seems to be all server-side. It's not as bad as I thought. Good news. (Now wait for GroupBy)

Comment: For no better words: holy sh*t. You are awesome! Works beautifully. I'll update my question with your answer in a few hours (have to run right now, but I had to test this). As @GertArnold said I half gave up on EF Core (I don't usually use it in production, but this is a smaller project, thought it would suffice), but guess I'll have to dig deeper into LINQ and EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

What if you didn't use EF Navigations properties but used manual joins with LINQ to EF?

```
var ans2 = (from b in dbContext.Buildings
            join f in dbContext.Floors on b.Id equals f.BuildingId into fj
            from f in fj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join r in dbContext.Rooms on f.Id equals r.FloorId into rj
            from r in rj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join ro in dbContext.RoomOccupancies on r.Id equals ro.RoomId
            join w in dbContext.WorkGroups on ro.WorkGroupId equals w.Id into wj
            from w in wj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where !w.IsFinished && w.StartDate < DateTime.Now
            select new BuildingDatableElementDTO() {
                BuildingId = b.Id,
                Name = b.Name,
                FloorCount = fj.Count(),
                RoomCount = rj.Count(),
                CurrentWorkerCount = wj.Sum(w => w.NumberOfEmployees)
           })
           .ToList();
```